# Shake listener detects too much shakes

Tags: java, android

I implemented a shake detector into my app to roll some dice. For every shake, every dice gets rolled once. The problem is that when I shake my phone, it "throws" the dice multiple times at once.

I've tried adding a delay and changing the sensitivity but none of that worked.

```
private final SensorEventListener sensorListener = new SensorEventListener() {

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent) {

        float x = sensorEvent.values[0];
        float y = sensorEvent.values[1];
        float z = sensorEvent.values[2];

        acelLast = acelVal;
        acelVal = (float) Math.sqrt((double) (x*x + y*y + z*z));
        float delta = acelVal - acelLast;
        shake = shake * 0.9f + delta;

        if (shake > 12) {
            // roll dice
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {

    }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can try this way to get the solution.

Use Handler which will add a time delay and for multiple senson response, it will take action on last satisfied condition only and previoulsy called once will be removed from callback.

```
private Handler handler = new Handler();

private Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        // roll dice     
    }
};

private final SensorEventListener sensorListener = new SensorEventListener() {

@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent) {

    float x = sensorEvent.values[0];
    float y = sensorEvent.values[1];
    float z = sensorEvent.values[2];

    acelLast = acelVal;
    acelVal = (float) Math.sqrt((double) (x*x + y*y + z*z));
    float delta = acelVal - acelLast;
    shake = shake * 0.9f + delta;

    if (shake > 12) {
        try {
            handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
            handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

@override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
}
```

You can delare a class variable and update that in the condition `if (shake > 12)` if you need anything from sensor so that that can be used in runnable.

Comment: This seems to be working great, thank you for your answer! Would you mind elaborating a bit more on the handler.removeCallbacks and handler.postDelayed parts?

Comment: `handler.postDelayed` gives a delay of 1000 ms (1 second) if condition mathc by the sensor call. In other word, it will take any action after a second and `handler.removeCallback` is used before that so that it will reset the delay timer for any repeative occurance of condition match (within the delay time duration) due to multiple sensor call.

Comment: As you mentioned it solved your issue then I hope the answer should be accepted.

Answer (score 0):

By adding a boolean 'rolled', and setting it true when the dice is rolled, you can only roll the dice once. And you can roll again by setting the value back to false.

```
private static boolean rolled = false;
private final SensorEventListener sensorListener = new SensorEventListener() {

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent) {

        float x = sensorEvent.values[0];
        float y = sensorEvent.values[1];
        float z = sensorEvent.values[2];

        acelLast = acelVal;
        acelVal = (float) Math.sqrt((double) (x*x + y*y + z*z));
        float delta = acelVal - acelLast;
        shake = shake * 0.9f + delta;

        if (shake > 12 && !rolled) {
            // roll dice
            rolled = true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {

    }
};
```

Comment: if rolled will be true then there should be a condition to make it false again somewhere otherwise how the dice will roll again for further sensor call?

Comment: You would set it to true when the dice roll has been handled(time delay is optional)

Comment: So when the dice rolled and you make the flag false back then the flag will be meaningless I think as for further repeative sensor call the condition `if (shake > 12 && !rolled) ` will satisfy again and the dice will roll multiple times.

Comment: when the flag is set to true, the dice can not be rolled again until the program(in another place) is set back to false. As an example if there are two calls of the sensor event, only the first one will role the dice, because after that the flag will be true and the dice will not be rolled by any sensor event, until the flag is set back to false.